# Checking results of a command in Bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-substitution

I am reading "Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide" at the moment.
There is some script that not working correctly on my machine:

```
HNAME=news-15.net # Notorious spammer.
# HNAME=$HOST
# Debug: test for localhost.
count=2 # Send only two pings.
if [[ `ping -c $count "$HNAME"` ]]
then
echo ""$HNAME" still up and broadcasting spam your way."
else
echo ""$HNAME" seems to be down. Pity."
fi
```

It always prints `$HNAME" still up and broadcasting spam your way.` - even with non-existing IP addresses. Can someone clarify what is the problem?

It works correctly when I use a hostname instead of an IP address.

Comment: I got `news-15.net seems to be down. Pity.`

Comment: Strange. What's the exit code of a `ping "$HNAME"`?

Comment: I've just added this 2 lines to the script just before the test statement.
`ping -c $count "$HNAME" > /dev/null 2>&1`
`echo "ping exit code is $?" # return 1`
It print 1 with nonexistent ip... But in the if statement it prints out "$HNAME up "

Comment: Can you make the title of the question more specific, please? Nearly all questions tagged "bash" could have the title "Bash script does not work" :)

Comment: @psmears I often find myself submitting edits to question titles for this very reason.  The Catch-22 of it is that the person asking the question tends not to know a good way to phrase it until the problem is identified. I just took a shot at it, and see if this passes peer review.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if [[ `ping -c $count "$HNAME"` ]]
```

This runs `ping` in a command substitution (using the old backtick syntax, instead of the saner `$(...)`). The resulting output is put on the command line, and then `[[ .. ]]`, tests to see if the output is empty. (That is, regular output. Command substitution doesn't capture error output, which would still be sent to the script's error output.)

If `ping` outputs anything, the test succeeds. E.g. on my system:

```
$ ping -c1 1.2.3.4 2>/dev/null
PING 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 1.2.3.4 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Since `1.2.3.4` is a valid IP address, `ping` tries to contact it. With an invalid IP address or a nonexisting hostname, it would only print an error, and the standard output would be empty.

A better way to test if a host is up would be to test the exit status of `ping`, and redirect its output away:

```
host=1.2.3.4
if ping -c1 "$host" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "'$host' is up"
else
    echo "'$host' does not respond (or invalid IP address/hostname)"
fi
```

---

Note that the quoting in the `echo` commands is off:

```
echo ""$HNAME" seems to be down."
```

This has an empty quoted string `""`, then an unquoted parameter expansion `$HNAME`, and then the quoted string `" seems to be down."`. For various reasons, it's better to quote all paremeter expansions, so use `"$var blahblah"`, or `"\"$var\" blahblah"` if you want to put quotes around the variable in the output.

See:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned in question `even with nonexistent ip`. If you pinging `IP` instead of a domain. You should try the below approach to get the desired result.

```
HNAME=192.168.1.21 
count=2 # Send only two pings.
if ping -c $count "$HNAME" 2> /dev/null
then
    echo "\"$HNAME\" still up and broadcasting spam your way."
else
    echo "\"$HNAME\" seems to be down. Pity."
fi
```

Comment: From a pedagogical standpoint, it might be helpful to explain *why* this is different i.e. that it tests the exit status of the ping command, rather than relying on whether or not it produces anything on standard output

Comment: @АртёмГригорьев because `ping` is notoriously "chatty" - it outputs messages to `stdout` in all sorts of cases - not directly indicative of success/failure